# how to solve the error of linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, linker-errors

I got one error when I run my app. The error is `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`.

The error shows me that there are 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64.

I could not find a solution. How can I fix this?

[image: i also put that screenshot of error in xcode]

Please help me for this issue.

Comment: What version of AFNetworking are you using?  How are you integrating it?

Comment: it is 3.0 version. and i am just download it from github and drag and drop in my project.

Comment: I think you need to seek help via the github issue tracker; I cannot find anything to indicate why this issue is occuring.

Comment: i will upload demo in github.download this demo

Comment: Your image of text isn't very helpful.  It can't be copied
into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, making other
users with the same problem less likely to find the answer
here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant
text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid
transcription errors).

Comment: Are there other projects / libraries referenced from your project? duplicate symbols often occur when a framework is statically linked by the main project and/or one or more other libraries.

Comment: thanks for your comment @MartinUllrich but i just want to inform you that there is no any other library add in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me as if you have both 2.0 and 3.0 AFNetworking in your project.  I don't see `AFURLConnectionOperation` in the 3.0 source but your link log shows it in conflict with `AFURLRequestSerialization`, which **is** in 3.0.

In fact, the github migration guide says:

> The following classes have been removed from AFNetworking 3.0:
>
> AFURLConnectionOperation
>
> AFHTTPRequestOperation
>
> AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Comment: This looks very plausible as the answer.